# Cannot select ID with Jquery from $.get() / $.load() function. Please Help Me?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My Javascript something like this

```
$('button').click(function(){
  //load the data and place inside to #content
});

$('#id-from-data-that-load').click(function(){
  //Do some action
});
```

So this is html tag

```
<button>Load</button>
<div id="content">
  //Empty Data
</div>
```

when button LOAD clicked html will be like this

```
<button>Load</button>
<div id="content">
  <div id="id-from-data-that-load">
    content that load
  </div>
</div>
```

BUT, when i clicked div id-from-data-load the function won't run.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use live for the div event instead. Here's what it should be:

```
$('#id-from-data-that-load').live("click", function(){
  //Do some action
});
```

Or alternatively you could also do this:

```
var submitted = false;

$('button').click(function(){
  // If the button was clicked before, we don't submit again.
  if (submitted == true) { return false; }

  // Set submitted to true, so when user clicks the button again,
  // this operation will not be processed one more time.
  submitted = true;

  //load the data and place inside to #content
  $.post("/getdata", {}, function(response) {
      //after the load happened we will insert the data into the div.
      $("#content").html(response);

      // Do the bindings here.
      $('#id-from-data-that-load').click(function(){
        //Do some action
      });
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thx niaher :D it's work... but on jquery documentation that live is deprecated and change to on(). I tried it but didn't work. Hm... btw thx alot :D

Comment: I didn't know about on() but yea it seems to be very similar to live(), so it should be pretty straight-forward to change. Make sure that you are using jQuery 1.7 though, because previous versions don't have the on() I think.

Comment: Hm... success using on with jQUery 1.7 but data submit to much. For example: when i click first time. It submit once. When i click second time. It submit twice. Etc... How to fix it??? very confuse.

Comment: Hi Kenjiro, the trick here is to introduce a variable which will determine if the button was clicked before or not. I've edited my 2nd example above by introducing "var submitted".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#id-from-data-that-load').live("click", function() {

                  alert($(this).attr("id");

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind events to elements loaded at runtime through either the `.live` handler or `.delegate` handler. That is because when you are binding events to elements they are not present on the dom. So .live and .delegate would help you achieve that. See example from @shree's answer

Answer (score 0):

Bind   id-from-data-that-load after data load in content.

```
  $('button').click(function(){
      //load the data and place inside to #content
      $('#id-from-data-that-load').click(function(){
        //Do some action
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the LIs you can hardcode the function name into the onclick attribute.

```
<li onclick="myFunction">Blah Blah Blah</li>
```