# Using .on() but data submit multiply

Tags: jquery

Before you gave a solution. Please read my first question [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005511/cannot-select-id-with-jquery-from-get-load-function-please-help-me/8005541#8005541)

So all my first problem have solved. But the data submit multiply. For example: when i click first time. It submit once. When i click second time. It submit twice. Etc... How to fix it??? very confuse

here my simple code

```
$(document).on('click','.page-info',function(){
        $('a[href|="#status-page"]').click(function(event){
            //DO THE SUBMIT DATA HERE
            event.preventDefault();

            //alert('testing');

            //href=#page-{id}
            var n='#status-page'.length;
            n++;

            var href=$(this).attr('href');
            //pageid=get the href {id}
            //pageid=id
            var pageid=href.substr(n);

            //Change status on database
            $.get(CHANGE_STATUS+'/'+pageid);

            //Change value status to active/disable
            var selector='#status-page-'+pageid;

            var status=$(this).html();

            if(status=='Active'){
                status='Disable';
            }
            else
            {
                status='Active';
            }

            //Change status
            $(selector).html($(this).html());
            $(this).html(status);

            var theStyle=(status!='Active')?'isGood':'isBad';
            $(selector).removeClass('isBad isGood').addClass(theStyle); // This code didn't work too :((
        });


    });
```

Here my simple HTML

```
<tr class="page-info">
    <td>
        <span class="isAction"><a href="#status-page-50">Disable</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a></span>
        <h5><a href="#page-50">Project P</a></h5>
        <p><strong>Project P</strong> - </p>
    </td>
    <td>2011-11-07 03:19:24</td>
    <td>
        <span class="cms_Status isBad">
            Disable        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On my page i have form that can add data with jQuery and do like this:

1. Post Data
2. Get Data
3. Appand Data after last ".page-info"

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a click handler on your `.page-info` `<tr>` element(s) and within this handler you add a click handler for the `<a>` element. So when you click on the `<a>` its handler gets called and then the event "bubbles up" to the containing `<tr>` - and the handler on the `<tr>` proceeds to add a second click handler to the `<a>`. Next time you click it adds a third click handler, then a fourth, etc. These multiple handlers do not replace each other, they all stay active and are called one after the other.

You can stop the event from "bubbling up" by adding `event.stopPropagation();` within the handler for the click on the `<a>`, but that won't actually help much because clicking elsewhere within the `<tr>` will still trigger its click adding more handlers to the `<a>`.

I don't understand why you need the handler on the `.page-info` `<tr>` in the first place. Can you explain that? My impulse is to just remove the `.page-info` `<tr>` click handler by deleting lines 1 and 5, i.e., the first and last lines of your code:

```
1  $(document).on('click','.page-info',function(){   // <-- delete
2     $('a[href|="#status-page"]').click(function(event){
3         // many lines of your code here
4     });
5  });                                               // <-- delete this line
```

(By the way, this answer is based soley on the information provided in this question - I'm feeling cranky and can't be bothered going off to read some other question to get the background for this one: how am I supposed to know which parts of the other question apply? You should provide all of the necessary background here.)

Comment: This problem have solved before i read my stackoverflow's question. So why i use on(). Because the content is dynamic. I get using AJAX. So if i use regular method jQuery didn't find the dynamic id. So i must use .on() or .live() method to solve that. But again i got another problem that i explain above. But i got solve by my self. Thx for your participate. Hehehehe....

Comment: @Kenjiro it is a good practice to share the answer , once you have resolved by yourself..